# Integrating django-select2 (autocomplete) and django-dynamic-formset (dynamic formsets)

Tags: django, django-forms

My app looks like this:

**forms.py:**

```
class SubForm(forms.ModelForm):

    myfield = GreatChoices()
    class Meta:
        model = Sub

MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(My, Sub, extra=1, form=SubForm)

class GreatChoices(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    queryset = Great.objects
```

**template.html**

```
<form id="great" method="post" action="{% url "great-add" %}">{% csrf_token %}                                                        
        {{ form }}                                                                                                                      
        <h3>Greats</h3>                                                                                                            
        <table>                                                                                                                         
                <tbody>                                                                                                                 
                        {% for f in formset.forms %}                                                                                    
                        <tr>                                                                                                            
                                <td>                                                                                                    
                                  {% if f.instance.pk %}{{ f.DELETE }}{% endif %}</td>                                                                                
                        </tr>                                                                                                           
                        {% endfor %}                                                                                                    
                </tbody>                                                                                                                
        </table>                                                                                                                        
        {{ formset.management_form }}                                                                                                   
    <input id="save_great" type="submit" value="Add">                                                                                  
</form>
```

and **template.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                                                                                  
    $('form#recipe tbody tr').formset({                                                                                         
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}'                                                                                          
    });
```

This almost works - I am able to add a single Sub object to my formset, and submit the form, and it `save()`s successfully.

However, if I click "add another" when I later click in the second input, cloned by django-dynamic-formset, the autocomplete from the *first* formset object is activated.  It seems as though select2 is not being made aware that a new row has been added...

I have done a bunch of reading and apparently formsets are a newish feature in select2:
https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/pull/127

I feel like I am really close to making it work and would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup but using Select2 directly instead of a Django app. I had the same issue with django-dynamic-formset and the fix for me was to modify `jquery.formset.js` to switch from `.clone(true)`, which is a clone with events, to `.clone(false)` which clones the structure but leaves out the jQuery events already hooked to the existing formset.

The change is simple, search for lines like these:

```
template = $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last').clone(true).removeAttr('id');

row = options.formTemplate.clone(true).removeClass('formset-custom-template'),
```

And change the `.clone(true)` to `.clone(false)`:

```
template = $('.' + options.formCssClass + ':last').clone(false).removeAttr('id');

row = options.formTemplate.clone(false).removeClass('formset-custom-template'),
```